# Get second letter in expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a list of machines listed like so:

```
M101
M102
M201
M202
M203
```

What I desire to return is

```
1
1
2
2
2
```

My question is how would I extract my desired return of the second charcter from my group expression? My field is `=Fields!machine.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following

`=MID(Fields!machine.Value,2,1)`

That will give you the second charcter in the string.